# Sublime Text 2 and Backspace(left_delete) issue

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I am having issue with `backspace` key binding which is not deleting words in **Sublime Text 2** only. In order to back space, either I have to highlight the character(s) that I want to delete and hit backspace or use `ctrl + z` to go back. And, `ctrl + backspace` erases the enter word rather than just one character(s). Also, `shift + backspace` has no effect eventhough it suppose to do the same thing as backspace.

I enabled `sublime_log_commands(True)` to display the key binding in real time and the log displays the proper binding taking place however it does not deleting any character(s) at all.

`backpace` => `command: left_delete`

`shift + backspace` => `command: left_delete`

&

`Ctrl + backspace` => `command: delete_word {"forward": false}` ( this one I am fine with)

Then, I installed `FindKeyConflicts` plug-in to see if there was any conflicts but the out put seems fine, IMO.

```
[shift+backspace]
left_delete                              Default
  .
  .
  .
[ctrl+shift+backspace]
left_delete                              Default               
run_macro_file                           Default
 .
 .
[ctrl+backspace]
delete_word                              Default 
.
 .
[backspace]
left_delete                              Default               
run_macro_file                            Default           
         [{"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled"}, {"operator":            
        "regex_contains", "operand": "^\"", "match_all": true, "key": "following_text"}, {"operator": 
        "regex_contains", "operand": "\"$", "match_all": true, "key": "preceding_text"}, {"operator": 
         "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true, "key": "selection_empty"}]
run_macro_file                           Default            
          [{"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled"}, {"operator": 
         "regex_contains", "operand": "^'", "match_all": true, "key": "following_text"}, {"operator": 
          "regex_contains", "operand": "'$", "match_all": true, "key": "preceding_text"}, {"operator": 
         "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true, "key": "selection_empty"}]
 run_macro_file                           Default              
          [{"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled"}, {"operator":  
          "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\)", "match_all": true, "key": "following_text"}, 
         {"operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\($", "match_all": true, "key": "preceding_text"}, 
          {"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true, "key": "selection_empty"}]
 run_macro_file                           Default               
         [{"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled"}, {"operator": 
         "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\]", "match_all": true, "key": "following_text"}, {"operator":  
         "regex_contains", "operand": "\\[$", "match_all": true, "key": "preceding_text"}, {"operator": 
           "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true, "key": "selection_empty"}]
 run_macro_file                           Default              
          [{"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled"}, {"operator": 
          "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\}", "match_all": true, "key": "following_text"}, 
           {"operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\{$", "match_all": true, "key": 
           "preceding_text"}, {"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true, "key": 
           "selection_empty"}]
run_macro_file                           CSS                  
          [{"operator": "equal", "operand": true, "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled"}, {"operator": 
          "regex_contains", "operand": "^;", "match_all": true, "key": "following_text"}, {"operator": 
          "regex_contains", "operand": ":$", "match_all": true, "key": "preceding_text"}, {"operator": 
           "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true, "key": "selection_empty"}, {"operator":  
          "equal", "operand": "source.css - meta.selector.css", "match_all": true, "key": "selector"}]
```

If anyone has any suggestion or work around on how to restore normal `backspace` operation, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Close all instances, go to your `Sublime Text 2` folder (http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) and rename to `Sublime Text 2 - Backup`.  Reopen sublime and see if backspace still broken.  This ensures you have the default bindings and no extra plugins.

Comment: @d_rail , I failed to respond back to your comment last time I saw it but what you have stated actually worked since someone else suggested I do that. What I still don't understand is what really caused the problem. Tanks tho

Comment: You just fixed the problem doing a clean "reinstall"? I still have this issue bugging me, after even deleting everything and reinstalling the nightly build. What version where you using? I think it has something to do with comments, because after the second comment I can't delete left nor right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said it fixed the issue, I will add it as an answer:

Close all instances, go to your [*Sublime Text 2* folder](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) and rename to *Sublime Text 2 - Backup*  (for linux, sublime-text-2.backup).  So that you don't lose any important stuff. Reopen sublime.  This will re-add the aforementioned folder with the default bindings and no extra plugins.

To see what is causing the issue: start adding back the plugins you were using, one by one, and see which breaks backspace.  It could also be an issue with conflicting key bindings.  So add personal bindings in the same manner as plugins.

Comment: In my case the problem was caused by the version of sublime I was Using. I was suscribed to the nightly builds. I changed back to the stable release with the same configuration I had and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, look, I searched how to solve this problem, it's this way:

1. re-install sublime text
2. with a hex editor software, I use Ghex for Fedora/Ubuntu, run it and menu File->Open, open the sublime text executable (installation folder), then, go to menu: edit->go to byte, and search by 0x590ADC, replace 33 with 32, save it and then execute and paste the license, this is all, backspace key should work.
   ‎
   Tested with Sublime Text 2.0.2 (linux version)

Answer (score 2):

You should 'reset' sublime text 2's settings. 
First close sublime text 2 and then open a terminal and type this:

```
mv ~/.config/sublime-text-2/ ~/.config/sublime-text-2.org
```

and then restart sublime text 2. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me (in SublimeText3), and it turns out I still had the "This is a free copy" alert open in the background.  Closing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on my Kubuntu installation. It's fairy simple:
When you try to crack your sublime, by changing the hex values of 
    33 42
to
    32 42
it will block the simple backspace (left_delete) and del (right_backspace) after 255 characters. (just try it: write 256 characters, and try to delete the last).

Workaround to this problem is to select the desired characters to be deleted, and than do a left_delete/right_delete.

If you want to solve this problem, do as other suggested, that is, to reinstall your sublime (with an unregistered version).

This problem is not found on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

easily go to Preferences -> Key Binding - Default 
search for keys aliases and edit whatever u want save it then its good to go

Answer (score 0):

I, too, faced the same problem today, and after searching through the documentation, I found the reason and solution to the problem.

This problem occurs because you may have accidentally changed some settings. So you have to revert those settings.

Now, go to Preferences -> settings -> user settings now check for "ignored_packages": ["Vintage"]
and remove it from user settings.
That's all nows your key shortcuts will work fine.